# How to check clicked element in custom listview row?

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

I have a custom ListView and this is it's row :

```
---------------------------
|--[ RelativeLayout 1 ]--|
|--[ RelativeLayout 2 ]--|
|--[ RelativeLayout 3 ]--|
---------------------------
```

I can use `setOnClickListener()` method in `BaseAdapter` for `RelativeLayout`, but I want to check which `RelativeLayout` is clicked, in `Activity Class`, and :

```
for RelativeLayout1 > call function1() in Activity
for RelativeLayout2 > call function2() in Activity
for RelativeLayout3 > call function3() in Activity
```

How can I do this?

Comment: have you seen my answer ? where have you reached with this ? would appreciate if you reply :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by adding the tag

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

to the outermost XML element in your list item layout. Then, for each of the `RelativeLayout`s, define an id element as

```
android:id="@+id/rel1"

android:id="@+id/rel2"

android:id="@+id/rel3"
```

Get a reference to each of these by calling:

```
RelativeLayout r1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rel1);
```

and set an `onClickListener` for each of them in the `getView()` method of your list's `Adapter`:

```
r1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        // do whatever you want here
    }
});
```

Try this. This will work.